# find all b and in $\mathbb{R}$ so $y''+2ay'+by'=e^{(b-a)x}$ is bounded on the interval $[0,\infty)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

find all b and in $\mathbb{R}$ so $y''+2ay'+by'=e^{(b-a)x}$ is bounded on the interval $[0,\infty)$

I believe it to be that $b<-a<0$, but I am not sure regarding the proof.

-Edit: here is a proof of mine, can someone spot my mistake?
$$ y''+2ay'+by'=e^{(b-a)x} \\ \Rightarrow
y'+2ay+by=\frac{e^{(b-a)x}}{b-a}+c \\ \Rightarrow
(ye^{(2a+b)x})'=\frac{e^{(2b+a)x}}{b-a}+ce^{(2a+b)x} \\ \Rightarrow
(ye^{(2a+b)x})=\frac{e^{(2b+a)x}}{(b-a)(2b+a)}+\frac{ce^{(2a+b)x}}{2a+b}+c_2\\ \Rightarrow
y=\frac{e^{(b-a)x}}{(b-a)(2b+a)}+\frac{c}{2a+b}+c_2e^{-(2a+b)} $$

Comment: To be clear, are you sure it is $by'$ and no $by$?
and more importantly, what about initial conditions $y(0)$ and $y'(0)$?

Comment: by' otherwise it's much harder question.

Comment: no info regarding initial conditions.

Comment: I highlighted the typos in red, check them and see if you get the same result. Also in the original equation, is the coefficient of $y'$, $a$ or $2a$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation is linear with constant coefficients, so we use Laplace transform

$$s^2Y(s)-sy(0)-y'(0)+(2a+b)(sY(s)-y(0))=\frac{1}{s-(b-a)} \\ \Rightarrow Y(s)(s(s+(2a+b)))=(2a+b+s)y(0)+y'(0)+\frac{1}{s-(b-a)} \\ \Rightarrow Y(s)=\frac{1}{s(s-(b-a))(s+(2a+b))}+\frac{(2a+b+s)}{s(s+(2a+b))}y(0)+\frac{1}{s(s+(2a+b))}y'(0)$$

The stability of a linear differential equation in the Laplace transform domain ($s-$plane) boils down to the fact that the region of convergence (ROC) must contain the imaginary axis

In order to have a stable system, all poles (roots of fractions on the RHS) must be in the Left Half Space of $s-$plane, Therefore $2a+b>0$ and $b-a<0$ (if we consider a causal system, so the ROC is of the form $\text{Real}[s]>d$ for some constant $d$) therefore $b<a,b>-2a$ or equivalently $-2a<b<a$. As we see the initial conditions is unimportant. Causal system means that we are seeking answers for $x\in [0,\infty]$.

Comment: I added a prof unfortunately I can make it a latex one. can you help out? I got a different results from you.

Comment: after fixing the problem you mentioned, I got almost the same as you did, beside that a must be a positive. i guess that you meant that otherwise the inequality doesn't make any sense. Am I right?

Comment: Can you please edit your question to correct form. Also if it is not positive, then as $x\rightarrow \infty$ so does $y$, because the general solution will be of the form $c_1e^{(b-a)x}+c_2e^{-(2a+b)x}$, did I got your question right?

Comment: added, yes you are right.